# How are large-scale matrices typeset?

Tags: matrices

I have a 36 by 36 matrix that I need to include in a statistics paper. I have the matrix in Maple (can be exported to Excel or Matlab), but I want it in "tex"-style inside my paper and in a small version (i.e., so it can fit on one page).

Is this possible?

Currently my (poor) solution is to print it out in Maple, zoom out so I can see everything, and then make an image of it. This can fit on one page, but quality-wise, it looks very bad, and it doesn't look latexified either.

Comment: Surely [Maple does support more than Excel and Matlab](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/managing/exportLaTeX)?

Comment: in `amsmath`, matrices are limited by default to 10 columns, but this can be reset with `\MaxMatrixCols=36` (or maybe a few more, just to be safe).  then you many need to use `\scalebox` (from the `graphicx` package) to shrink the result to fit within the margins.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that Maple does support LaTeX. There seems to be two options:

- [either whole file export (From the File menu, select Export As. The Export As dialog opens.)](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/managing/exportLaTeX)
- or single expression export function conveniently named [`latex`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=latex)